# Bash loop to make directory, if numerical id found in file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to use `awk` to create sub-directories in a directory (which is always the last line of `file1`, each block separated by an empty line), if the number in line 2 (always the first 6 digits in the format xx-xxxx) of `file2` is found in `$2` of `file1`.

The directory will already be created in `/path/to/directory`. In the example below, `Directory2_2` already exists in `/path/to/directory` and since `19-0003`, `19-0004` and `19-0005` are found in `$2` of `file1`, they are moved to `Directory2_2`.

**file1**

```
xxxx_006 19-0000_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz
xxxx_007 19-0001_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz
Directory1_1

xxxx_008 19-0003_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz
xxxx_009 19-0004_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz
xxxx_020 19-0005_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz
Directory2_2
```

**file2**

```
xxxx
19-0003-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
yyyy
xxxx
19-0004-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
yyyy
xxxx
19-0005-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
yyyy
```

**awk in bash for loop**

```
for f in $(awk { print cut -d'_' -f1 }' file2); do
    [[ "$f" == $2 ]] && mkdir -p "$f" /path/to/directory
done
```

**desired output**

```
Directory2_2
 19-0003-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
 19-0004-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
 19-0005-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the directory names don't contain spaces (below file1 processed in paragraph-mode and file2 in line-mode.):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { for(i=2; i<NF; i+=2) a[substr($i,1,7)] = $NF; next }
     { k = substr($0, 1, 7) } 
     k in a { cmd = sprintf("mkdir -p %s/%s", a[k], $0); print(cmd); }
' RS= file1 RS='\n' file2
#mkdir -p Directory2_2/19-0003-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
#mkdir -p Directory2_2/19-0004-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
#mkdir -p Directory2_2/19-0005-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
```

change **print(cmd)** to **system(cmd)** to actually run the command.

**Note**: if the directory names contain spaces, you might need to setup IFS='\n' in order to use $NF for the base directory in file1:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { for(i=1; i<NF; i++) a[substr($i,index($i," ")+1,7)] = $NF; next }                              
     { k = substr($0, 1, 7) } 
     k in a { cmd = sprintf("mkdir -p \"%s\"/\"%s\"", a[k], $0); print(cmd); }
' FS='\n' RS= file1 RS='\n' file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v path_val="/your_path/"  '
FNR==NR{
  if($0 ~ /^[0-9]+/){
      a[substr($0,1,7)]=$0
  }
  next
}
/^Directory/{
  if(count==value){
      print "Directory " $0 " all elements are present." ORS "Going to write shell script code  now..."
      print $0 ORS val
      print "*************************************************"
      print "if [[ -d " path_val $0 " ]]" ORS "then" ORS\
            "    cd " path_val $0 ORS "    mkdir " val ORS\
            "    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]" ORS "    then" ORS \
            "         echo " s1 "Directories named "\
            val s1 " created successfully in path " path_val\
            "." s1 ORS "    else" ORS "         echo " s1\ 
            "kindly check from your end once seems directories not created." s1\
            ORS "    fi" ORS "else" ORS "    echo " s1\
            "Please check seems base directory " path_val " NOT present itself."\
            s1 ORS "fi"
  }
  count=val=value=""
}
($3 in a){
  val=(val?val OFS a[$3]:a[$3])
  count++
}
/^xxx/{
  value++
}'  Input_file2 FS="[ _]" Input_file1
```

***Explanation what code does is:***

1- Code has variable named `/your_path/` which is your BASE path where directories will be created etc.

2- It will check if all the lines coming before `Directory_...`(para by para) keyword from Input_file1 is present in Input_file2 if yes, then it will print output of those lines along with directory name + it will write code on console too(bash code which checks about your base directory path and then creates the matched directories inside base directory). As of now I am simply printing it you could either take it to `.ksh` file(as an output file) and could run it OR you could add `| bash` at the end of this code. I haven't tested it I leave this up to OP.

Following will be the output:

```
Directory Directory2_2 all elements are present.
Going to write shell script code  now...
Directory2_2
19-0003-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111 19-0004-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111 19-0005-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
*************************************************
if [[ -d /your_path/Directory2_2 ]]
then
    cd /your_path/Directory2_2
    mkdir 19-0003-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111 19-0004-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111 19-0005-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
         echo Directories named 19-0003-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111 19-0004-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111 19-0005-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111 created successfully in path /your_path/.
    else
         echo kindly check from your end once seems directories not created.
    fi
else
    echo Please check seems base directory /your_path/ NOT present itself.
fi
```

***PS:*** As mentioned above take final shell code which should create directories in system either in output_file or run it by using `| bash` etc at end of `awk` code I haven't tested it. Please DO NOT run code without testing. Statements are very simply you can go through them and should test it in a test directory/test environment only.

Comment: Thank you both :).