# Awk to create directory then subdirectory with zip in it

Tags: awk

The `awk` below will create sub-directories in a directory (which is always the last line of file1, each block separated by an empty line), if the number in line 2 (always the first 6 digits in the format xx-xxxx) of file2 is found in `$2` of file1. This is the current awk output.

If there is a match and a sub-directory is created in a directory then the corresponding line1 https in file2 will always be a link to a zip file for download. I can not seem to create that link in the sub-folder, download and extract the .zip. the download code executes and downloads the zip but has to manually added to the terminal. i apoogize for the long post, wanted to include all details to solve this

**file1**

```
xxx_006 19-0000_xxx-yyy-aaa
xxx_007 19-0001_zzz-bbb-ccc
FolderName_001_001

yyyy_0287 19-0v02-xxx
yyyy_0289 19-0v31-xxxx
yyyy_0293 19-0v05-xxxx
FolderName_002_002
```

**file2**

```
https://xx.yy.zz/path/to/file.zip
19-0v05-xxx_000_001
 cc112233
https://xx.yy.zz/path/to/download/file.zip
19-0v31-xxx-001-000
bb4456784
https://xx.yy.zz/path/to/file.zip
19-0v02-xxx_000_001
aaa331232
```

**awk edit**

```
cmd_fmt='mkdir -p "%s/%s"
# run the awk command
awk -v cmd_fmt="$cmd_fmt" '
# create an associative array (key/value pairs) based on the file1
NR==FNR { for(i=2; i<NF; i+=2) a[substr($i,1,7)] = $NF; next } 

# retrieve the first 7-char of each line in file2 as the key to test 
 against the above hash
{ k = substr($0, 1, 7) }

# if find k, then print
k in a { print a[k] "\t" $0 "\t" l }
# save prev line to 'l' which is supposed to be the URL
{ l = $0  } 
' RS= file1 RS='\n' file2 | while IFS=$'\t' read -r base_dir sub_dir link; 
do
echo "download [$link] to '$base_dir/$sub_dir'"
# bash command lines to make sub-folders and download files
 create the format text used in sprintf() to run the desired shell commands
cd "%s/%s" && curl -O -v -k -X GET %s -H "Content-Type:application/x- www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization:xxxx" && { filename="%s"; unzip 
"${filename##*/}"; }'
done
```

**desired awk output**

```
FolderName_002_002 --- directory
    19-0v02-xxx_000_001  --- sub folder
    https://xx.yy.zz/path/to/file.zip  --- zip and extracted downloaded to sub-folder
    19-0v05-xxx_000_001  --- sub-folder
    https://xx.yy.zz/path/to/file.zip  --- zip and extracted downloaded to sub-folder
    19-0v31-xxx-001-000  --- sub-folder
    https://xx.yy.zz/path/to/file.zip  --- zip and extracted downloaded to sub-folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is related to this one: [Bash loop to make directory, if numerical id found in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994039/bash-loop-to-make-directory-if-numerical-id-found-in-file/54995383)

You can run all commands in one awk `system()` funcion, just organize them properly, for example:

```
# create the format text used in sprintf() to run the desired shell commands
cmd_fmt='mkdir -p "%s/%s" && cd "%s/%s" && curl -O -v -k -X GET %s -H "Content- Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization:xxx" && { filename="%s"; unzip "${filename##*/}" && rm -f "${filename##*/}"; }'

# run the awk command
awk -v cmd_fmt="$cmd_fmt" '
    # create an associative array (key/value pairs) based on the file1
    NR==FNR { for(i=2; i<NF; i+=2) a[substr($i,1,7)] = $NF; next } 

    # retrieve the first 7-char of each line in file2 as the key to test against the above hash
    { k = substr($0, 1, 7) }

    # if find k, then run the system command    
    k in a { cmd = sprintf(cmd_fmt, a[k], $0, a[k], $0, l, l); print(cmd) }

    # save prev line to 'l' which is supposed to be the URL
    { l = $0  } 
' RS= file1 RS='\n' file2
```

change `print` to `system` to execute the command.

**Note:** the above `unzip` and `rm` commands might not work if file names contains URL encoded chars.

**Update based on your `awk edit`:**

you can also just print the required info from `awk` line and then process them in bash, no need to do everything in `awk`(also remove the line to define `cmd_fmt` in your `awk edit` section):

```
awk '
    # create an associative array (key/value pairs) based on the file1
    NR==FNR { for(i=2; i<NF; i+=2) a[substr($i,1,7)] = $NF; next } 

    # retrieve the first 7-char of each line in file2 as the key to test against the above hash
    { k = substr($0, 1, 7) }

    # if find k, then print
    k in a { print a[k] "\t" $0 "\t" l }

    # save prev line to 'l' which is supposed to be the URL
    { l = $0  } 

' RS= file1 RS='\n' file2 | while IFS=$'\t' read -r base_dir sub_dir link; do
    echo "download [$link] to '$base_dir/$sub_dir'"
    # bash command lines to make sub-folders and download files
    mkdir -p "$base_dir/$sub_dir" 
    cd "$base_dir/$sub_dir"

    if curl -O -v -k -X GET "$link" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization:xxxx" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "  + processing $link"
        # remove query_string from the link, since it might contains '/'
        filename="${link%\?*}"
        # remove path from filename and run `unzip`
        unzip "${filename##*/}" 
    else
        echo "  + error downloading: $link"
    fi

    # return to the base directory if it's a relative path
    # if all are absolute paths, then just comment out the following line
    cd ../..
done
```

**Note:** I did not test the `curl` line and dont know what the filenames could be for different links. `filename="${link##*/}"` is to remove all chars before the last '/', which will leave filename and potential query_strings. `"${filename%\?*}"` is to remove the trailing query strings from `filename`. Actually filename downloaded by your `curl` command might be different which you will have to check and adjust from your end.

Comment: Thank you very much :).

Comment: The zip archive `$filename` is extracted with as same name, so I need to `rename` `$filename` to `tmp` and unzip `tmp`, but I can not seem to without making the command error. Thank you :).


    && { filename="%s"; unzip "${filename##*/}" && rm -f "${filename##*/}"; }'

Comment: @cm0728, you are very welcome:). Not sure about your actual data files, but it seems to be much easier to just post-processing the actual files under bash. the awk `system()` function might not invoke the bash and thus the bash `parameter expansion` will not work.

Comment: I can see the output on the terminal but the directories are not created.  I added the `cd "%s/%s" && curl` under the `#bash download`. Thank you :).

Comment: addind the `curl` didn't work. Is there something else?  Thank you :).

Comment: what is your current code? looks it was running under `awk`. The problem with `system()` under awk is that it might not have the same environment variables as in your current shell (for example, can't find PATH to curl). it would be much easier when post-processing these files under `bash`. or you can have awk to `print` all commands, if these commands are fine, just pipe to bash, i.e. `awk '...' file1 file2 | bash`. make sure all paths (absolute or relative) are correctly reflected to your local HD.

Comment: updated my post. `%s` is formatting string which you will need to change to actual bash variables. you will need to check the actual filename saved from the `curl` command. the code I supplied will stripe the path and query_strings.